# I am being verbally harassed by customers what can I do?

Tags: harassment, sexual-harassment

I work for Walmart and wanted to ask. If I feel unsafe or uncomfortable at work due to being verbally harassed by customers what can I do? Is there anything I can do?

Like I keep getting hit on/ flirted with by men that come into the store.

Comment: Have you tried talking about it with your manager ?

Comment: Will Walmart support any sexual harassment claims by you against customers? Is the retail environment where you want to be?

Comment: Have you read the employee manual? Spoken to your manager? Worst case scenario, record the harassment (or ask a coworker to record it), call the police if you feel unsafe, document what has been happening to you over email/SMS with your employer, maintain a paper trail of those incidents, and absolutely DO NOT trust your employer if they do not have your back.

Comment: I'm going to email my HR lead about it because I have requested a transfer to a different department.

Comment: While waiting for the transfer, you might want to work out a signal with other workers so that they can assist you when those events happen. Having others back you up can help.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment on the question:

> I'm going to email my HR lead about it because I have requested a
> transfer to a different department.

Yes this is a reason to talk to HR. They will want to know what your manger/shift lead has done when you talked to them.

Check you employee manual, regarding how this should be reported and documented. Also check the break room for signs/posters related to labor laws in your city/state/country. These may also apply.

Note: I am not sure what being in a different department will do, if both departments interact with customers. But that is an issue for HR and management to consider.